# When building a new PC should I consider how powerful the CPU is comparing to the graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, computer-building, gaming

When building a gaming PC with i5 modern processor, does it matter if I get 1060 or 1070 graphics card? I've heard an opinion that i5 "matches" 1060 and buying 1070 would waste money since 1070 would not be fully utilized by games since i5 would be the limiting factor. What about 2070?

Is this an accurate claim? Will most games not benefit from a better GPU, when CPU stays the same? How do I find out if CPU or GPU is a limiting factor, not for a particular game, but for gaming in general?

**Edit**

Just to clarify: this question does ask to recommend any particular hardware and as such is not hardware recommendation question. Instead, it asks whether one should consider how powerful the CPU is comparing to the graphic card when building a new PC. Any reference of particular hardware parts in the question is just to make the question more concrete.

Comment: Actually, no hardware recommendens here. The answer will be. It depends. If you have a low graphics online game, with many players, you will need a faster cpu, if it's single player and graphics intensive with physics, you will need a fast GPU.

Comment: Just to clarify: this question does ask to recommend any particular hardware. It asks whether one should consider how powerful the CPU is comparing to the graphic card when building a new PC. Any reference of particular hardware parts in the question is just to make the question more concrete.

Comment: As David says, it depends a lot on the game. Some games, particularly simulation based RTS games and games with a lot of physics or player interactions, can be limited by the CPU doing scene changes and updates and starve the GPU of meaningful updates meaning repeated frames or lower frame rates. It does depend a lot on the game and how it is written.

Comment: There is a huge difference between a GTX 1060 and a GTX 1070.  Let alone the fact there are numerous models within both those product lines.

Answer (score 1):

The concern about the CPU compared to the GPU is true, but in a limited fashion.

Most games rely heavily on the GPU, and therefore anything modern (core i3,5,7,9) is likely to benefit from any faster GPU.

A core i5 should not be significantly bottlenecked even by a 2080ti or radeon vii.  Sure if you find a pentium III 450 yes it will bottleneck the GPU, but you will still have the fastest graphics a p3 450 has ever seen.  (Yes, I know a p3 450 can't have a pci-express slot so it more of a thought process.)

I don't remember where I saw the study, but basically above 6 threads even directx 12 does not use them enough to be effectively except in 1% of use cases.

Yes, some games use a lot more CPU than others, and in those cases you will notice the difference.  However, before directx 12 all previously versions of directx used 1 maybe 2 cores at most.  3Dmark demonstrates that directx 11 in multi-thread mode achieves at best a couple a percentage point gains.  Therefore its might as well not be multi-threaded.

If your games supports directx12 or vulkan there is a significant advantage which is also demonstrated in 3dmark futuremark.  However, above 6 threads the benefits drop off.

Given how few games support vulkan or directx 12 the benefit from super high end CPU is limited.

You need to examine the types of games your playing, because as @Mokubai says RTS games use a lot more CPU because they have to do strategy computations.  However, the graphics part of the game will still be faster with a faster GPU and your money will not be wasted.  Also you may still want to consider the faster GPUs because more and more programs are taking advantage of OpenCL/stream processors/CUDA to allow the GPU to accelerate other tasks.

Adobe products like creative suite/photoshop, and video editing software is already being accelerated by the GPU.

In short, buy the faster GPU and don't worry about marginal loses caused by a slightly slower CPU.

Comment: Thank you I feel this answers my question. I'll accept your answer in a few days if a better one does not pop up.